# How to add Login Form of wordpress into your page?

Tags: wordpress

Guys can anyone give me a guide on how to add login form and also how to customize it??? thanks for the help...

Answer (score 3):

You can add a login form pretty easily to any page using the [wp_login_form()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) function. [Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/08/30/adding-a-login-form-to-a-page) has a good article with more information, and also shows you how you could couple this with a shortcode for use in posts and pages.

Once you have the form embedded you can style it with CSS, just like other elements of your theme.

I hope this helps!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to help. If it did solve your problem, don't forget that you can mark this as solved :)